# pow.cx raising an exception when running rails server works just fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, rack-pow

I'm having no problem running on rails server (`localhost:3000`) but for the same code running on pow.cs ... I'm getting this error:

```
Error starting application 
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it. 
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rack/jsonp 
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require' 
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require' 
~/config.ru:2:in `block in ' 
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval' 
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
```

any ideas?

Comment: can you add `config.ru` contents?

Comment: also make sure that pow is using the same gems (through rvm, rbenv, etc) as `rails s`